# Powershell certificate issuer is wrong

Tags: powershell, certificate, get-childitem

I get a specific certificate using

```
$certificate = Get-Childitem -path $path - Recurse | where {$_.Subject -match $cn} 
| Sort-Object -Property NotAfter -Descending | Select-Object -first 1
```

Later I need the certificates issuer and subject:

```
($certificate).Subject
($certificate).Issuer
```

Here's my problem: Issuer does not return the expected value but the same value as Subject. The other columns work.

When I use "dir cert - Recurse" I can see the right values, but when I added "|Format-List - Property *" at the end of my Get-Childitem call I can see that Issuer is already the wrong value and the expected value is in non of the other columns.

This is my first time posting a question, I hope you can help me :)

Comment: "but the same value as Subject." - sounds like a self-signed certificate. Try filtering them out by changing the `Where-Object` filter block to: `{$_.Subject -match $cn -and $_.Subject -ne $_.Issuer}`

Comment: That seems to solve the issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mathias suggested, I needed to filter out self-signed certificates:

```
... |Where-Object {$_.Subject -match $cn -and $_.Subject -ne $_.Issuer}
```